# In MVC 3 how we can redirect user to default URL, depending on its role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
           {
               routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
               routes.MapRoute(
                   "Default", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                   new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
               );

           }
```

**If current user is admin then he should be redirect to admin page on entering root url ???**

Comment: Upon entering which route url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways (most of them custom) but I'd use default MVC functionality and keep routes as they are but rather have two controller actions depending on security role:

```
// actions part of UserController

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}

[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[ActionName("Index")]
[AdminsOnly]
public ActionResult IndexAdmin()
{
    ...
}
```

This would automatically run the second one when users would be members of a particular role. But if you only have a particular user (admin) then you could change that attribute to be:

```
[Authorize(Users = "admin")]
```

If you're using some custom mechanism to define user type/role membership, you can always write your own authorization action filter.

But `AuthoriseAttribute` is not an action selector filter so MVC wouldn't be able to distinguish between the two withou creating a custom action selector filter `AdminsOnlyAttribute`. This one would do the check for you and you wouldn't the error that there were several actions for a request. In case of writing this custom filter, you can then also simply remove the `AuthorizeAttribute` as your action selector will check that already.

### Other contenders

#### Custom `Route`

If this is not what you'd like you can always write your own custom `Route` class that redirects users to particular area depending on their username/role membership... Although redirection could as well be part of your `Login` action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginCredentials user)
{
    // authenticate
    ...
    if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { area = "Admin" });
    }
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```

This action assumes there's Admin area in your application.

#### Custom route constraint

The other possibility is to have custom route constraints. So you would actually define two routes but one having a particular constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { area = "Admin", controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { isAdmin = new AdminRouteConstraint() }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

This way you'd be able to route admins to **admin** area of your application and provide them with particular functionality they have there. But it doesn't bean that they need an admin area. That's just my route definition. You can define route defaults the way that you want.

Comment: How did you manage to define 2 actions on the same controller with the same name and the same arguments? That's not valid C# code.

Comment: if user is already logged in and he type root URL in browser then ???
as in MVC it will get root URL from Global.asax.
Suppose root URL is /User for "ABC" Role but for "XYZ" role it is not accessible and then user with "XYZ" role type root URL then he will get security message, but i need to redirect him to his default url.

Comment: so the question is Can i redirect him from Global.asax?

Comment: @Arun: My first case with two action methods works fine in this scenario although you will have coupled actions in all cases that need different scenarios based on user role. But apart from that as I mentioned there are other *custom* ways. You could write a route constraint that would take your roles into account. Or have a custom  `Route` class that would be aware of this. I'd likely try the constraint first.

Comment: @Arun: Read these two blog posts. First one by me and second one by Stephen Walther: [Action method selectors](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/using-custom-action-method-selector.html) and [custom route constraints](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this redirect in your Index action:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            // The user is an administrator => redirect him to his own page
            return RedirectToAction("SomeActionName", "SomeControllerName", new { area = "admin" });
        }

        // the use is either not authenticated or not in the admin role => render some view
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this could be an option, but this will cause double response time...client won't be happy